# how to write regex for wild cards like .(any character not a whitespace) and \s(space) in OR condition

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have the following String.

> `some<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\"><!--\n" +
>                   "   tempArr[4728] = 0; \n" +
>                   "//--></script>text`

This includes spaces and other non-alpha characters.

I need a regex to replace the script tag and its contents, so the result should be:

> `some text`

I tried the following regex for that.

```
<script(.)*(\s)*(.)*(\s)*(.)*<\/script>
```

I'm able to get the output but when I observe the regex I can see duplicate conditions (multiple copies of `(.)*` and `(\s)*`).

How can I simplify that with a regex `OR`?

I tried using a character class - see [here](https://regexr.com/3qhif).

Comment: So you mean Java or JavaScript?

Comment: I'll get that html(which contains script tags) to Java. I need to write a regex in Java.

Comment: `<.*>` should be the brutal way of doing it. Although to ensure it only changes the script you can do `<script.*script>`

Comment: Use a parser. Regex is not the way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a reluctant quantifier and dot-all flag to match the entire `script` tag in a straightforward way:

```
(?s)<script\b.*?</script>
```

Use it like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?s)<script\\b.*?</script>", "");
```

The `(?s)` flag makes the dot match newline too.

Putting `\b`, which means “word boundary”, after `script` means it won’t accidentally match a longer tag name that *starts* with `script`, eg `<scriptX>`.

`.*?` matches as *few* chars as possible, so it will match only up to the next instance of `</script>` (in case there as several script tags).

Comment: This is working perfectly. All I need to learn about reluctant quantifier now. Thanks.

Comment: @Pavan if it helps, `.*` is greedy (consumes as *much* input as possible while still matching), and `.*?` is reluctant (consumes as *little* input as possible while still matching)

Comment: @Bohemain perfect

Comment: @Pavan somebody silently downvoted, so I looked for something that someone could complain about and thought that adding `\b` might be it. I don’t think you’ll need it, but for completeness it won’t hurt to add it in - see edited answer.